# How should I build my store for complex object with methods?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-store

My object is like:

```js
const inventory = {
  maxSlots: 24,
  content: [
    {id: "item_01", quantity: 5, slotId: 0},
    {id: "item_02", quantity: 2, slotId: 2},
    {id: "item_03", quantity: 1, slotId: 6},
  ]
};
```

I need custom methods like:

- `inventory.getRemainingSlots()`
- `inventory.getFirstFreeSlotid()`
- `inventory.addItem()` (this one depends on `inventory.getFirstFreeSlotid()`)

How should I make this object reactive?

- Single writable?
- Custom store with `get`, `set`, `update` and `subscribe` methods?
- Class instance with writable?
- One writable for each single property, then a store of stores?

I've reached this point so far:

`inventoryStore.js`

```js
function createStore() {
    const { subscribe, set, update } = writable({
        maxSlots: 8,
        content: [
            { id: "item_01", quantity: 5, slotId: 0 },
            { id: "item_02", quantity: 2, slotId: 2 },
            { id: "item_03", quantity: 1, slotId: 6 },
        ],
    });

    return {
        // Store methods
        subscribe,
        set,
        update,
        get: () => get({ subscribe }),

        // Custom methods
        getContent: () => {
            // I can't use this in .svelte files 
            return inventoryStore.get().content;
        },
        getFirstFreeSlotId: () => {
            const content = inventoryStore.get().content;
            const maxSlots = inventoryStore.get().inventoryMaxSlots;

            for (let _slotId = 0; _slotId < maxSlots; _slotId++) {
                const foundItem = content.find(_x => _x.slotId === _slotId);

                if (!foundItem?.id) {
                    return _slotId;
                }
            }

            return -1;
        }
    };
}

export const inventoryStore = createStore();
```

Comment: Seems like maybe what you really want to look into are derived stores which can react to the values of other stores. Then you wouldn't really even need a custom store for any of what you want to do https://learn.svelte.dev/tutorial/derived-stores

Comment: @JHeth this worked for me, post it as answer and I'll mark as the correct one!

Comment: @Icuruk great! Sounds like you figured it out yourself though. You can answer your own question and accept it as the correct answer to help future users who may run into a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

`/stores/inventoryStore`

```js
import { derived, writable } from "svelte/store";
import { get } from "svelte/store";

const inventoryStore = writable({
    toolbarMaxSlots: 8,
    inventoryMaxSlots: 24,
    /** @type {Array<{id: string, quantity: number, slotId: number}>} */
    content: [
        {id: "item_01", quantity: 5, slotId: 0},
        {id: "item_02", quantity: 2, slotId: 2},
        {id: "item_03", quantity: 1, slotId: 6},
    ],
});

export const inventory = {
    _store: inventoryStore,
    subscribe: inventoryStore.subscribe,
    set: inventoryStore.set,
    update: inventoryStore.update,
    get,

    addItem: function ({ id = "", quantity = 1 }) {
        return this.update((_prev) => {
            const newItem = {
                id,
                quantity,
                slotId: 1, // todo: get first free slow
            };
            _prev.content = [..._prev.content, newItem];

            return _prev;
        });
    },

    // usable in js
    getItems: function () {
        return this.get(this._store).content;
    },
    
    // usable in svelte
    getDerivedItems: function () {
        return derived(this._store, ($store) => {
            return $store.content
        })
    }
};
```

`+page.svelte`

```html
<script>
    import { inventory } from "./stores/inventoryStore";

    const derivedItems = inventory.getDerivedItems();
</script>

<pre>
    {JSON.stringify($derivedItems)}
</pre>
```